# Css opacity not mentioned within CSS properties

Tags: css

Why opacity is not mentioned within [CSS properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html)?

```
div {
    opacity: 0.3;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean ?

Comment: is opacity is not a 'css property'? Link provided aims to be 'full css properties spec'. Why is opacity not mentioned within them?

Comment: `opacity` is CSS3. The page you reference is CSS2.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/all-properties.en.html, it's a pretty good reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you provided was for css2 opacity was not added until 3.0.

For full support, browser prefixes/filters would be needed for older versions

You can find the specs here for css3 [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)